# C# class to XML (xmlserializaion) problem

Tags: c#, xml

Currently i am working with xml and have to populate xml file from C# object serializaion.Suppost below is the xml format what i want to do.

```
<DVD>
<Starring>
    <Star position="actor">
        Tom Hanks
    </Star>
   <Star position="actress">
        Robin Wright
    </Star>
<Title>Forrest Gump</Title>
</Starring>
</DVD>
```

I have two classes DVD and Star.

```
Public class DVD
{
  string title;
  public string Title{get{return title;}set {title=value;}}
  List<Star> Starring=new List<Star>();
}
public class Star
{
   string star;
   string pos;
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Position{get{return pos;}set{pos=value;}}
   //Actually i don't want this property as a xmlelement
    public String StarName
   {
     get{return star;}
     set {star=value;} 
   }
}
```

Result from serialization is

```
<DVD>
<Starring>
    <Star position="actor">
        <StarName>Tom Hanks</StarName>
    </Star>
   <Star position="actress">
        <StarName>Robin Wright</StarName>
    </Star>
<Title>Forrest Gump</Title>
</Starring>
</DVD>
```

My problem is i don't find the way how to wrap Actor and Actress name without having  StarName node.Is there a way to do this?.Any idea would be very appreciate.

Comment: I don't believe you!  Given your code, the Title element will be outside the Starring element - in fact a peer of that element.

Answer (score 5):

Use XmlTextAttribute on StarName property.